# ImageField not accepting value from html file in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am making a custom CMS platform in Django. I want to upload a featured image from user.

Here is my forms.py

```
class CkEditorForm(ModelForm):
    ..........
    ..........
    featuredImage = forms.ImageField(required=True)
```

My models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ..........
    ..........
    featuredImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="featured_image/")
```

My HTML Template

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
     {{myForm.featuredImage}}
   </div>
```

I used one more method in template but it didn't work for me-

```
<input type="file" name="featuredImage" accept="image/*" required id="id_featuredImage">
```

Note- Image is successfully uploaded via Django admin panel, But not working when I try to upload via Templates (HTML file)

Also, it was working when I use this method to render my form in html

```
{{myForm.as_p}}
```

But I want to render each form's input method as differently.

```
{{myForm.category}}
{{myForm.tags}}
{{myForm.featuredImage}}
```

Here is the views.py

```
def postView(request):

    if request.method== "GET":
        form = CkEditorForm()
        return render(request,"post/post.html",{'myForm':CkEditorForm})

    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':         
            form = CkEditorForm(request.POST)            
            if form.is_valid():            
                form.save()
                return render(request,"post/post.html",{'myForm':CkEditorForm})
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Error")
        return render(request,"post/post.html",{'myForm':CkEditorForm})
```

Comment: Is the form named `myForms` or `myForm`? You say it worked when you used `myForms` with an "s"

Comment: it is myForm not myForms. Typos

Comment: I edited the question. It was a spelling mistake. Sorry for that

Comment: Do the inputs get rendered? What do you get?

Comment: Yes they are visible in the html templates. https://prnt.sc/rssihf

Comment: It's possible that you haven't set the correct attributes on your form tag if the form isn't submitting the file. It should be `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: I use this enctype="multipart/form-data" in my form tag but it didn't work for me. Also, I get every data of the form tag except ImageField

Comment: Can you share your view? Are you passing `request.POST` and `request.FILES`?

Comment: You need to pass `request.FILES` when you are uploading files - `form = CkEditorForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my Views.py and it worked for me...

```
def postView(request):

    if request.method== "GET":
        form = CkEditorForm()
        return render(request,"post/post.html",{'myForm':CkEditorForm})

    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':         
            form = CkEditorForm(request.POST,request.FILES)            
            if form.is_valid():            
                form.save()
                return render(request,"post/post.html",{'myForm':CkEditorForm})
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Error")
        return render(request,"post/post.html",{'myForm':CkEditorForm})
```

I just change this. Add request.FILES to get image data.

```
form = CkEditorForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
```